# python3.5 aiohttp, request post, json format and 405 errors

Tags: javascript, python, json, aiohttp

I finally sign up because I have no more idea for my problem.
I use asyncio and aiohttp for my back-end part and javascript for the front-end part. But I stuck with a 405 error. (I precise I am a beginner with theses libraries)

I wish retrieve a json from a post request. Here the javascript function:

```
function postJson (data){

    $.ajax({

           url : 'http://localhost:8080/postJson',
           type : 'POST',
           dataType : 'json',
           contentType : 'application/json',
           data  : data, //data are ready at json format, I do not think I need to use JSON.stringify ? I does not change anything to the error anywhere
           success : function(code_html, statut){ 
             console.log("success POST");
           },

           error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
             console.log("error POST");
           }

        });
  }
```

and the python code:

```
async def postJson(request): 
   data = await request.post()
   #some code
   return Response()


@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('POST', '/postJson', postJson)

    handler = app.make_handler()
    srv = yield from loop.create_server(handler, '127.0.0.1', 8080)
    print("Server started at http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    return srv, handler

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
srv, handler = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections())
```

With this code I get a 405 error. Here a bite of what says firebug about the request:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 // so json is not in the list.
```

however, if I take back the line `contentType : 'application/json'` in my javascript file, it works (but the request send a object called `MultiDictProxy` and I don't understand how to use the function `json()` from `aiohttp.web` package ([here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web_reference.html)).

I really need to get a json object. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the solution. I post the conclusion here for people who could be interested:

python side:

replace the line `app.router.add_route('POST', '/postJson', postConf)` by

```
app.router.add_route('POST', '/postJson', postConf, expect_handler = aiohttp.web.Request.json)
```

in the postJson method:

replace `data = await request.post()` by `data = await request.json()`

and on javascript side:

```
data  : JSON.stringify(data)
```

with this, my method works.

Comment: Please drop `expect_handler` parameter -- you use it improperly. Hopefully client doesn't send EXPECT header

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine except two things:

1. `@asyncio.coroutine` and `async with` are mutually exclusive
2. `postJson()` must return response instance, not `None`

Comment: thanks, I edited my message. But it does not change the error. I have looked for on my side about the route syntax, which could maybe use an expect handler, but I am not sure of how... (cf aiohttp server doc: add_route(method, path, handler, *, name=None, expect_handler=None) ) The expect_handler param accept a coroutine and there is a coroutine called json. But It need a parameter and I do not see what it could be.